# How to return an array with unhappy numbers removed?

Tags: matlab, function

I'm quite new to using MATLAB, and am still trying to understand how to make this particular function. I understand the formula for performing this on paper, but I'm having trouble translating it into the required MATLAB syntax.

How would a function be written such that it takes an array of numbers, and returns that array with unhappy numbers removed i.e. only happy numbers remaining?

EDIT - Proving and input and output

Input:

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Output:

```
array = [7, 13, 19, 23, 31, 79, 97]
```

A happy number is such that a number's squared digits summed eventually equal to 1, or continue the process indefinitely [as seen here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number).

Comment: Add an example input and output. Also add the condition on what base a number be considered unhappy.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a number is happy? Or just how to remove certain numbers from a list (because you can already write Matlab code to determine if the number is happy)?

Comment: Sorry for communicating so poorly. I want to know how to read an array and keep only the numbers that are happy.

Comment: The main work here is checking whether a given number is happy. You should try to write a function to do that (along the lines of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Programming_example), for example), and then ask about specific issues if you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small function (which might be further improved) to test the "happines" of a number.

Current version only works with scalar and one dim. array.

Input: the scalar or array to be tested

Output:

1) an index: happy (1) unhappy(0)

2) the list of happy number within the input set

3) the list of unhappy number within the input set

Running the function with the input specified in the question, the function returns:

```
function [is_happy,h_array,unh_array]=happy_number(in_val)
%
% Output:
%    is_happy: 1 ==> the numberis happy
%              0 ==> the numberis unhappy
%    h_array: happy numbers within input
%    unh_array: unhappy numbers within input
%

% Input validity check (to be improved)
s=size(in_val);
if(iscell(in_val) || isstr(in_val) || isstruct(in_val) ...
      || ~find(s,1) || length(s) >= 3 || sum(floor(in_val)-in_val) ~= 0)
   error('Only scalar or 1 dim array supported')
end
% Vars initialization
h_array=[];
unh_array=[];
h_array_cnt=1;
unh_array_cnt=1;
h_unh_cnt=1;
% Loop through input number
for i=1:length(in_val)
   seq=[];
   n=in_val(i);
   seq_cnt=1;
   seq(seq_cnt)=n;
% Test if the number is happy
   while(n ~= 1 && n ~= 4)
% Decompose the number in its digits      
      sn=num2str(n);
      nv=str2num(sn(:));
      seq_cnt=seq_cnt+1;
      seq(seq_cnt)=sum(nv.^2);
      n=seq(seq_cnt);
   end
% Set and display results   
   if(n == 1)
      disp(['Number ' num2str(seq(1)) ' is HAPPY'])
      is_happy(h_unh_cnt)=1;
      h_unh_cnt=h_unh_cnt+1;
      h_array(h_array_cnt)=seq(1);
      h_array_cnt=h_array_cnt+1;
   else
      disp(['Number ' num2str(seq(1)) ' is UNHAPPY'])
      is_happy(h_unh_cnt)=0;
      h_unh_cnt=h_unh_cnt+1;
      unh_array(unh_array_cnt)=seq(1);
      unh_array_cnt=unh_array_cnt+1;
   end

end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the index of your unhappy numbers. You can remove them by writing :

```
array(unhappy_index) = [];
```

If you do not have the unhappy index, you can find them by using the followng command:

```
find()
```